# R's DBI function dbGetQuery automatically corrects my dbname casing

Tags: mysql, r

I'm a beginner in R; I'm running into this problem where my query statement gets case corrected when trying to query from MySQL, causing problems

```
data <- dbGetQuery(con, 
   'SELECT * FROM `S3screeningdb`.table'
   )
```

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :
> could not run statement: Table 's3screeningdb.table' doesn't exist

I can clearly see here that S3screeningdb has been changed to s3screeningdb when running this function, causing the query to fail. I've read the documentation on DBI's dbGetQuery and can't seem to find any answers to fix this. Anybody got ideas for me to try?

My database connection to MySQL was done using the following

```
con <- dbConnect(
  RMySQL::MySQL(), 
  host = "localhost", 
  username = "root", 
  password = "password",
  dbname = "S3screeningdb",
  port = 3306
)
```

As a sidenote, my other attempts involve:

1. Using `dbSendStatement` instead of `dbGetQuery`. Same error
2. Specifying the dbname at the connection, instead of in the query statement. Same error

Comment: What type of database are you connecting to? How are you creating the `con` object?

Comment: @MrFlick

Thanks for the questions for clarification. I am connecting to a MySQL database using the following:

```
con <- dbConnect(
  RMySQL::MySQL(), 
  host = "localhost", 
  username = "root", 
  password = "password",
  dbname = "S3screeningdb",
  port = 3306
)
```

I've noticed that connecting to other databases with this schema name doesn't cause this problem. It is looking like this problem is specific to the database I'm connecting to

Comment: What does `dbListTables(con)` return? Does ` dbGetQuery(con, 'SELECT * FROM S3screeningdb.table')` without the extra table quoting give a different error message?

Comment: @MrFlick it properly returns the table names of the schema S3screeningdb...

Edit: It does not properly return the table names. The table name that I am very specifically trying to query from is not there. That's odd, since I am able to see and query from it using mysql workbench.

Comment: Well, if the table isn't listed, something else is going on. I don't think this is related to lowercase table names at all. Maybe it's a user/permission thing as to who can access that table? Perhaps it would be a good idea to contact your database administrator for guidance.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I think this has brought me closer to the problem. I'll take a better look from here.